# About integer promotion in C, short

Tags: c, integer

```
void main(){
    char c;
    unsigned char uc;
    unsigned short us1, us2;
    short s1, s2;

    c = 0xf0; uc = 0xf0;
    us1 = c; us2 = uc;
    printf("us1 = %x, \t us2 = %x\n", us1, us2);
    s1 = c; s2 = uc;
    printf("s1 = %x, \t s2 = %x\n", s1, s2);
}
```

Result:
us1 = fff0,    us2 = f0
s1  = fffffff0, s2 = f0

why is the s1 like this? eventhough in 32-bit and sizeof short is 2bytes

Comment: Why do you use `void main()`?

Comment: It is one of these “if you knew about that you wouldn't have to ask the question” remark, but `%x` expects an `unsigned int`, so to be completely correct you should apply it like this: `printf("%x", (unsigned int)us1);`. Both the signed and unsigned short arguments are promoted to `int` with the syntax you use.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I don't believe casting `unsigned short` to `unsigned int` is functionally any different to casting it to plain `int` (the default). The bit pattern, promotion rules, and so on, are all identical. You don't start running into differences until you start using the numbers in larger calculations, and by then the fact that it was once a short is long forgotten.

Comment: @ams C99's 7.24.2.1:9 does not say “if any argument does not have the same bit pattern as the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined”. It says “If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.”. Therefore, `printf("%x", 1)` and `printf("%x", (unsigned short)1)` are undefined behavior. That they work in practice is irrelevant to the notion of “undefined behavior”.

Comment: @PascalCuoq integer promotion is perfectly well defined behaviour. `unsigned short` will be zero-extended to `int`, and `signed short` will be sign-extended to `int`. You can choose to extend to `unsigned int`, but the effect is the same (with the extend variant being defined by the source type).

Comment: @ams And I didn't say it wasn't, I said that `printf("%x", 1)` is undefined behavior and I cited the clause in the C99 standard that makes it so.

Comment: @PascalCuoq No, no, it isn't. There is no `short`. It's a figment of your imagination. It doesn't exist until you write to memory, or force it with a cast (at which point it probably gets extended and truncated  and extended again). Besides, your example uses a literal constant. You get undefined behaviour passing `double` where an `int` is expected (to variadic functions), but `short` is always promoted to `int`, just as `float` is always promoted to `double`.

Comment: @ams C99 7.24.2.1:8 “o,u,x,X The **unsigned int** argument …” (emphasis in the original document)

Comment: @ams I am not saying it is undefined because a `short` is passed for `%x`. I am saying that it is undefined because an `int` is passed for `%x` (which expects an `unsigned int`).

Comment: @PascalCuoq OK fair point, it seems we're arguing round in circles. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `short` is promoted to `int` in the variable-argument call to `printf()`.